# Utility for Monitoring IOPS on servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, performance-monitoring, io

We recently ran the Dell Performance Analysis Collection kit which monitors your servers via WMI for 24 hours. You send the file off to Dell and they return a report with graphs of IOPS and MB/S disk usage.

This uncovered some interesting stats for us which we'd like to look further into. This is just a sales tool for Dell, but is there a similar tool that we can download/purchase for use that generates our own reports? Even better would be ot tell us what processes are using the IO.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen Dell do this, but maybe it was something like [PAL](http://www.petri.co.il/analyze-windows-performance-logs.htm).  There's also [Windows Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749154.aspx) and [Perfmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx), both are free.  I was going to also mention [IOMeter](http://www.iometer.org/) but it doesn't sound like you want to generate your own load.

Answer (score 1):

DPACK is free and available at http://support.dell.com
Then search for dpack for the latest update

This is a service carried over from their purchase of compellent (imo the best SAN solution in the market)

Answer (score -3):

It is a very good tool, actually I am in contact with my Dell account manager about how to get it...
Some briev overview is here:

http://content.dell.com/uk/en/business/d/business~smb~sb360~en/Documents~DPACK-overview.pdf.aspx